# How to get the creation date of a table on Firebird 2.5

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and need to get the date of creation of a table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT RDB$RELATION_NAME
  FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS
 WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG=0;
```

I've tried with this table but there isn't any date field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the creation date of a table as this information is not recorded anywhere.